# Login page is not working in JSp when i put Empty User name and password

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
    String userid = request.getParameter("uname");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from members where uname='" + userid
            + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");
    if (rs.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
        //out.println("welcome " + userid);
        //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }

    else {
        out.println("Invalid password <a href='FirstPage.jsp'>try again</a>");
    }
%>
```

This is my code for a Login page.

I am validating from the database and checking if a user exists. 
If the user exists, login succeeds, if not, an error message is shown to the user. 
When I try to login with an empty user name and password, it also allows to login.

Please check my code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just a sidenote: You are aware that your script is highly vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: is you table have empty records?

Comment: I dont But it work in ALl Browser what will Mistake ?

Comment: Please give us your database users table rows.

Comment: Thanx its working fine There was one Blank record

Comment: Try to use prepared statements

Comment: As said subash, do you have a empty user in you database? If not the case, it won't match.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the empty String before doing your validation like :

```
if(userid == null || pwd == null) {
    request.sendRedirect("home.jsp"); // return; // do what ever you want to exit. }
}
```